# Is throwing error on invalid function argument a BC breaking change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backwards-compatibility

My package exports following function:

```
function myFunc (arg1) {
  someInternalVar.push(arg1);
}
```

In docs it clearly states that this function accepts `string` or `array<string>` where string might be either `"a"` or `"b"` and (if array passed) each element might also be one of those values. However in there is no argument validation code right now and passing `"c"` just silently ignores it. I would like to add following argument validation to prevent users from accidently passing wrong values:

- if arg1 type is not string and not array throw TypeError
- if arg1 type is string but is not "a" and not "b" throw TypeError
- if arg1 type is array and any of the elements breaks one of two rules above throw TypeError

The question is if it will be backwards-compatibility breaking change and I should consider releasing new major version?

Comment: If you aren't changing the expectations of the API, only enforcing them, then I would not call that a breaking change. If anyone's code breaks from it, then they were using it incorrectly anyway.

Comment: What kind of workflow are you using? If you're using traditional semantic versioning, then no: this would be a patch that enforces expected public API behavior.

Comment: It's not an API breaking change, but it's certainly a backwards compatibility breaking change - if anyone has written code that depends on this behaviour, and you're worried about backwards compatibility, then yes it's a breaking change.  But really only _you_ can decide if it's a breaking change to your users.